# Function to find value given column and row across multiple worksheets in excel

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have an array of data on excel worksheet1 with month of the year in the first column then each column is a different year. On worksheet2, I have a given year. I need to pull the data value from the cell on the worksheet1 given the year(column header) specified on worksheet2 from a a specified row on worksheet1 (month). I have tried using indirect,address,and vlookup functions and they do not seem to understand that I am trying to call data from both worksheet1 and worksheet2.

Worksheet1

```
      1970 1971 1972  
Jan    3   4 5  
Feb    5 6 7  
March  7 8 9
```

Worksheet2

```
Jan  
1971  ??
```

I need the "4" in worksheet1 to go where the question marks are in worksheet2. (above is just a simple example).

Comment: The code explained on this webpage should work for you! http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-the-vlookup-hlookup-combination-formula/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!A:Z,0,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!1:1,0)),Sheet1!A:A,A1)
```

This assumes that the formula is in B2 on Sheet2 and all data starts in A1 on their relative sheets.

[image]

Comment: This assumes I already know the value is in A2 on Worksheet1. What I am asking is how to pull that value from A2 if I only know that I want the value from column header "1971" or "B" and row header "Jan" or "1" .

Comment: This uses both Jan and 1971 to return 4.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: @JMP0629 See edit I changed to SUMIFS but as you can see from the picture, it returns `4` like it should

Comment: Sorry. Yes. I understand now. However, I keep getting the "there is a problem with this function" error that I have gotten on every thing I have tried. The function is fine and another function I use with the same sheetname! call also works fine.

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` in the formula and make sure you are using the SUMIFS.